# Should we delete the 'python-crash' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A question with this tag appeared in the feed today, when I clicked on the [python-crash](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-crash) tag, I found that only 2 questions had the tag.

Does this specific tag add value? Should we retag to [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) instead?

Comment: This tag had been burninated before I looked for the questions that had been tagged with it so I have set [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that we should simply burninate the [python-crash](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-crash) tag by removing it from those two questions.

Instead I would encourage Python users to read the error messages that they receive, so that they may better respond to them, and use Python error tags like [syntaxerror](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntaxerror), [attributeerror](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attributeerror), [nameerror](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameerror), etc.

I recommend against using the [error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag on the grounds of it being too granular to be useful. That is a tag that I would be supportive of blacklisting.

I would not use the [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag on ArcPy or PyQGIS but I acknowledge the case for using it on Python libraries with far fewer Q&As here at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4374/115